# Is it always given that ground has lower resistance than output even If output is far closer in an inverting nmos?

Tags: ground, inverter, grounding, nmos, common-source

Currently I'm learning about MOSFETs (N-MOS and P-MOS) --basically how a transistor works. My question is why does the current always prefer the grounding output even though it is further away than the regular output?

Here is a picture of an N-MOS inverter: [image: A picture of a N-mos being an inverter]

Now in the picture I've drawn a resistance on the output. Is it always assumed that the output has higher resistance than the grounding?

How does it work? I'm confused as to why the current flows towards the ground when the output is so close to it. And, I've learned that current takes path of LEAST resistance so surely the output has a higher resistance then right?

Sorry if I'm unclear.

Comment: Your circuit is flawed and won't work. Out connects to 5 volts and the MOSFET is incidentally also connected to 5 volts and plays no role in this circuit other than to get hot when activated.

Comment: This question certainly shows some confusion on the part of the asker, but I don't think that's a problem. After all, asking questions is how we resolve our confusion about things. I don't see how we could reasonably ask them to _first_ resolve all of their confusion and only _then_ ask questions.

Comment: @TannerSwett - Thank you for that excellent comment, which needs to be understood more often by those who are excessively critical of new OPs. || For other readers, that comment was in reply to a previous hostile comment which has been deleted, as it broke the [Code of Conduct](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/conduct/abusive-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you mean when you say something is "close" to something else. Are you referring to physical distance, or electrical resistance?

It saddens me to see you relying on phrases like "current takes the path of least resistance", which might be true, all other things being equal. However it's rare that all other things are equal. That's one of those hand-wavy phrases that only serve to confuse, in the end. Forget that phrase now, and maybe come back to it when you have a better foundation to your electronics knowledge.

Here you have an output that isn't connected to anything. That output path cannot be passing *any* current, regardless of the resistance of the resistor you have drawn there, since there's a current-halting brick wall (air, an infinite resistance) at the far end. For any current to flow, you'll need to connect OUT to somewhere else in the circuit.

If you did that, and current did flow that way, the amount of current flowing would have nothing to do with the transistor, or its state. That's because the left end of your resistor is connected to a fixed potential of +5V. There's nothing the transistor can do to change that fact. Because that potential is fixed, the only way to vary current in the resistor is to vary the potential at its *other* end, OUT.

Secondly, the transistor is connected with top (drain, presumably) connected to a fixed potential of +5V, and bottom (source) connected to a fixed 0V. The only thing to know here is that there's a fixed difference of \$(+5V) - (0V) = 5V\$ between drain and source, and this fact is true regardless of anything else in the circuit, including that other resistor.

That resistor therefore does not influence, in any way, the current that will flow down through the transistor. Even if you connected OUT to somewhere meaningful, to allow some current to pass that way, the voltage across the transistor remains the same (5V), the resistance between drain and source inside the transistor didn't change, so the current flowing within the transistor will not be affected.

To summarise so far, in your circuit as you have drawn it, the transistor's state cannot possibly influence the current flowing in the resistor. Likewise, the resistor's resistance, and any current flowing that way (of which there isn't any) cannot possibly influence current in the transistor. Current in those two elements are completely independent of one another, because all the potentials in this schematic are fixed. The phrase "current takes the path of least resistance" is meaningless and useless here, and in most circumstances.

To shed some light on how your question could be improved, and illustrate more useful concepts, here's the circuit again, modified to allow the potential at node X to change:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqyc8n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've given "output" current I3 somewhere to go, by connecting it to ground (0V). I've inserted an additional resistance R1 between the FET's drain and +5V, which allows the potential at the drain (node X) to vary, instead of being tied to a fixed +5V.

Let's imagine the transistor in two states, as "on" as it can be, and as "off" as it can be, like in a digital system. Of course it could also be anywhere between those two extremes, but I don't want to muddy the waters with that. For now it's either off or on. When its on, it presents a very very low resistance between drain and source, say 1Ω.

When it's off, its drain-to-source resistance becomes almost infinite. I say almost, because it can only be really high (perhaps many millions of ohms), but for our purposes here, I'll assume it's infinite. In that state, it can be removed from the circuit, because it becomes an "open" circuit, passing no current.

Below left, the transistor is off, removed from the circuit, and to the right the transistor is on, replaced by its equivalent resistance of 1&Omega:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsMHjm.png)</sup>

Now let me install some ammeters and voltmeters to see what the potentials and currents are everywhere. It looks complex, but that's just because it's cluttered now. All I've done is add some measurement equipment that doesn't alter the circuit's behaviour at all:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq2faD.png)</sup>

The first thing I want to point out is how currents \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$ in both situations seem to concur with your statement "current takes the path of least resistance". On the left, the transistor is gone, there's an infinite resistance to ground, and no current can flow via that path; \$I_2 = 0A\$. \$I_3\$ has a comparatively small resistance to traverse, only 100Ω, and \$I_3 = 25mA\$. This is indeed in keeping with that principle.

Then, to the right we have a low transistor resistance of \$R_3 = 1\Omega\$, with a much greater current \$I_2=49mA\$, compared to the mere \$I_3=490\mu A\$ through R2. Again, clearly current is preferring the path of low resistance.

However, if the phrase were to be relied upon entirely to describe what's happening, then we would expect the total current \$I_3\$ on the left to equal \$I_3\$ on the right, and we would expect that same current to simply take a different path depending on the state of the transistor. Clearly that's not the case. Other things have changed, principally the potential \$V_X\$ at node X. When the transistor switched on, \$V_X\$ fell from +2.5V to nearly 0V, illustrating my point above about the phrase relying on "all other things being equal". They almost never are.

Clearly voltages and currents *everywhere* (except the fixed +5V and 0V nodes) have changed. That's because by changing the transistor's resistance, you change the *total resiatnce* of the path between +5V and 0V. This system behaves as a whole, and no part of it is independent of any other. It can only be analysed as a whole, using maths as I'll address below. In this sense, the phrase "current takes the path of least resistance" is pathetically inadequate to describe any part of this system.

Do yourself a favour, forget the idea that current always takes the path of least resistance. It has some truth to it, and it can guide you intuitively in certain circumstances, but in 99% of cases, it can burn you, sometimes literally.

The truth is that to understand the behaviour of any circuit, you first need to understand that voltage and current are two sides of the same coin. When one changes, so does the other. They are both part of the same underlying phenomenon we call electricity. Not only that, when current in one place changes, not only do the voltages there change too, but voltages and current *everywhere* else in the circuit change. It's one of the biggest challenges in electronics: to keep a voltage constant regardless of changes to flowing currents, or to keep some current fixed in spite of voltages everywhere flapping around.

With practice you will develop an intuition that will enable you to predict behaviour with little or no mathematics, but in reality, there is only one way to describe and understand what's happening in any circuit: using maths.

At the very least, you *need* to understand three laws:

- ***[Ohm's Law](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-2/voltage-current-resistance-relate/)***
  This relates the voltage across something, the difference in potential between two points, to the current flowing between those points. It's always obeyed. For instance, the voltage \$V_{R1}\$ across R1a above left is \$V_{R1}=(+5V) - (+2.5V) = 2.5V\$, and the current through it is \$I_1 = 25mA\$. Applying Ohm's law \$R=\frac{V}{I}\$ to that resistor, we always find that it agrees with reality:
  $$ R_1 = \frac{V_{R1}}{I_1} = \frac{2.5V}{0.025A} = 100\Omega$$
- ***[Kirchhoff's Current Law](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/kirchhoffs-current-law.html)***
  This relates currents leaving or entering some junction, such as node X above right. The sum of all currents entering must equal the sum of all currents leaving a junction, otherwise you have a leak somehwhere, like water in a junction of pipes. It's always obeyed, check for yourself in the circuit above right:
  $$ I_1 = I_2 + I_3 = 49.02mA + 490.2\mu A = 49.51mA $$
- ***[Kirchhoff's Voltage Law](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/dccircuits/kirchhoffs-voltage-law.html)***
  This relates voltages across elements around a loop. It states (paraphrased) that as you travel around any loop in a circuit, eventually arriving back where you started, you must end up at the same potential you started with, regardless of what changes in potential you encounter on the way. The same way that as you travel around town, in a big loop, regardless of what hills or stairs or valleys you cross, you must always end up at the same elevation (say, above sea level) that you started at. In other words, the sum of all potential changes you encounter around any loop, must be zero.
  Above right, Starting at node X, with a potential of 49.02mV, going upwards, first we cross R1, encountering a rise (positive change) in potential of \$5V-49.02mV=4.951V\$ (the voltage across that resistor). Then dropping down to ground, we encounter a fall (negative change) of 5V. Finally, to return to X we jump over R3, which has +49.02mV across it:
  $$ (+4.951V) + (-5V) + (+49.02mV) = 0 $$

These laws are sufficient to completely describe the instantaneous state of any circuit, or any part of a circuit, and by writing the various equations down, and solving them simultaneously, you can find all currents, and all voltages. The bad news is that this is mathematics, and it is tedious.

The good news is that while tedious, it's not that difficult, and by mastering these three laws, you are a good chunk of the way to mastering electronics in general. As you journey you will gain intuition, and be able to predict behaviour without resorting to complex systems of equations, but until then you are kind of stuck with it. Sorry.

I am a little jealous that I won't ever have the opportunity to experience the epiphanies and "aha" moments that learning all this has afforded me over the years. I hope  you have as much fun learning it all as I did.

---

#### Update

Here's an example of why you can't trust the phrase "current prefers the path of least resistance":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm0ILg.png)</sup>

The phrase is valid on the left, where the right-hand branch (via R3) has twice the resistance of the left branch (via R2), and as you would expect, current through the higher resistance is half that through the lower resistance.

For the right circuit, though, current through the *higher* resistance  path is *three times greater*. All because I changed the potential at the bottom of R3, from 0V to −12V.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. The output of the circuit like the one shown in your drawing is assumed to be connected to a high impedance (resistance with some extra caveats) input. This can be a problem if it doesn't turn out to be high impedance but yes, your understanding is correct.

(And, like @Andyaka points out, you need a resistor between +5V and your MOSFET.)

Answer (score 0):

## The rule of understanding

From my life practice, I have found that ***things in life are understood through similar but simpler things***. The paradox is that things are not understood as things themselves but through other things.

For example, no matter how much you study the transistor device in semiconductor engineering, it is not enough to understand transistor circuits. There is a need for something else that is not learned there, but long before that in electrical circuits and in life.

## Building the common-source stage

Perhaps it is best to reinvent step by step the most elementary transistor amplifier stage to understand the meaning of things.

### Converting the voltage into resistance

Regardless of all the complexities of the (MOS) transistor, generally speaking, it does one simple thing in amplifier circuits - ***introduces adjustable losses in the form of a voltage drop***. So does the much simpler *variable resistor* in electrical circuits. They both do it the same way - ***by inserting resistance into the circuit and changing it***. So the simple functional idea of a transistor is as a *voltage controlled variable resistor* (*voltage-to-resistance converter*).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5zC6e.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Indeed, there is a "small" difference - a resistor is a linear element with a constant resistance, whereas a transistor is a non-linear element with a "self-changing" (dynamic) resistance, but this is not essential to understanding the basic idea of the transistor amplifier stage. It is a concept, and details get in the way of understanding concepts.

### Converting the resistance into current

**Variable resistor:** The resistance is only a parameter that can control some "true" electrical quantity, most simply the current. For this purpose, we (the "input voltage source":-) supply the variable resistor Rds with a voltage source Vdd and by changing the resistance we adjust the current Id = Vdd/Rds = 10 mA (Ohm's law) looking at the "ideal" ammeter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGRqVE.png)</sup>

To get a better idea of the resistor's behavior, let's measure and plot its IV curves for three resistance values - 1 kΩ, 2 kΩ and 10 kΩ. As you can see from the graphs, at 10 V the corresponding currents are 10 mA, 5 mA and 1 mA.

[image: STEP 2.1]

**Transistor:** Similarly, we can consider the *drain-source* section of a MOS transistor as some kind of such a "variable resistor" that changes its resistance under control of the input voltage. Thus, by applying a supply voltage Vdd to it, it can regulate the current in the same manner as above, and we can connect a low-resistance load to use the current. By adjusting the gate voltage, we can change the transistor drain-source "resistance" to set the same currents of 10 mA, 5 mA and 1 mA as above.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feTF6d.png)</sup>

As you can see from the graphs below, at 10 V they correspond to the same resistance values of 1 kΩ, 2 kΩ and 10 kΩ as above.

[image: STEP 2.2]

### Converting the current into voltage

For a number of reasons, circuits operate primarily with voltage; therefore we need to convert the current of the transistor into a voltage. For this purpose, we include a resistor Rd in ​​series to the drain-source part, and a voltage drop VRd = Id.Rd appears across it (to simplify the schematic, I have set 1 kΩ internal resistance of the ammeter making it a "visualized resistor"). So we can connect a high-resistance "floating" load in parallel to the resistor. Note that the output voltage is not inverted - as the input voltage increases, the output voltage also increases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6pq0b.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 3a]

[image: STEP 3b]

### Taking the complementary voltage

Accordingly, the remaining voltage Vds = Vdd - Id.Rd is obtained across the transistor. So the two elements in series form a sort of *controllable voltage divider*, and we can use one of the two voltage drops as an output by connecting a high-resistance load in parallel to the respective element (to simplify the schematic, I have set 10 MΩ internal resistance of the voltmeter making it a "visualized load resistor" as above). We prefer Vds because it is referenced to ground and the load (the next stage) is grounded. So we connect the grounded load in parallel to the drain-source part.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4GNJm.png)</sup>

Note that now the output voltage is inverted - as the input voltage increases, the output voltage decreases; hence the name "inverting amplifier stage".

[image: STEP 4a]

[image: STEP 4b]

### Block diagram

Let's finally outline and label the components of this configuration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGsO0y.png)</sup>

As you can see from the block diagram, it consists of four cascaded elements - input voltage source Vin, voltage-to-current converter V->I, current-to-voltage converter I->V, and load L. The cascaded V-I and I-to-V converter constitute the amplifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRB1JB.png)</sup>